# wcf in .net core custome binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, wcf

I am trying to consume wcf custom binding (CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement) in .net core project.

I have working example in .net framework 4.8 but I Can't reference it from core.

Because this is full message security it will not be support also in the dotnet\wcf (github repo for core)

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3424

What are my options? I am force to call this old wcf tech, so any idea will be welcome.
I can use signle R with window service(send commands) but it seem just too complicated way

Comment: You could have a look at a project called corewcf to see if that might help you?

Comment: Here is [the example](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/4227). Maybe this will help you build your project.